# Is it possible to populate a torrent file with a peer?

Tags: bittorrent

With a trackerless torrent, is there a way to create or edit it so my hostname/IP and port already in the peers list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your hostname/IP and port-number in the `nodes`-section of the torrent-file.

For a detailed description you can look at the specification [here](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) , or look at the overview provided on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#Distributed_hash_tables)

An alternative to that approach is to run your own torrent-tracker, and add yourself as tracker to the file. There is a very good step-by-step tutorial available at [bootstrike.com](http://bootstrike.com/Articles/CreateTorrent/) on how to do this with µtorrent.

**Edit:** As [doktoro-reichard](https://superuser.com/users/228536/doktoro-reichard) pointed out (Thank you), there is a program by [BitTorrent](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) to sync files/folders between devices. It encrypts traffic and announcements, so only devices/people with correct keys can see/access/download the data. This seems to be the optimal solution for your usecase.

Comment: Thanks for that. But I wonder if there's a way that doesn't require DHT, as I never enable that.

Comment: Can you maybe go into detail on what you exactly want to accomplish?

Comment: Sure. I want to share a large file (too large for any webservice), so I've been creating torrents with public trackers, and sharing the `.torrent` file with the recipient. There are problems with this: public trackers are often overloaded, or slow; the recipient hasn't got the corrent port open; or any number of issues along the way. The simpliest way around this is to have the recipient manually add me as a peer using my IP:Port. If I could just populate the torrent file with this information, it would save a lot of time. Imagine the recipient finds the adding peer step to be too complicated.

Comment: For that purpose you can also act as your own tracker-server, eg. using µTorrent (updated my answer accordingly)

Comment: Ahh, nice. I use uTorrent, but didn't know it had a built-in tracker.

Comment: There is also [Bittorent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html‎), if transferring to a single recipient is what you want. Although not answering your question, it seems like more in touch with what you want to do.

Comment: Aah, very interesting product, didnt know about it till now ;) Added it to the answer